# aligning vertical centers of icon and text in .row

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

im stuck again with "basics", anyway, I'm having trouble making this example :

[image: Example]

Basicly I want icon and "Feature 1" to be aligned on top and centered as seen on picture (the cyan lines) and then below them a random paragraph.

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="top-align text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            <h3>We're Creative</h3>            
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    


</body>
```

CSS3

```
.top-align{

display:inline;

}
```

So, my idea here was to make icon and "Feature 1" paragraph be "inline" so i made custom css and separate div tag for these 2 things (icon and paragraph), but unfortunately it wont work, here's live version if anyone is interested

http://i1cevic.com

Comment: vertical-align:middle + inline-block for both icone and title ;)

Comment: ty, it works just great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapper div does not need display: inline. An inline element will render as if it is a letter in a word - each character is an inline element. A `<span>` defaults to display: inline - it takes up the next available space on the line.

Once the wrapper div.top-align has display: inline removed, give the h3 a display property of inline or inline-block. Either will do. This will allow the icon and h3 to act like two adjacent words and they will respond to the text-align: center applied by the wrapper div.

Even better, you can accomplish this without a wrapper div around the icon + h3. The icon defaults to a display of inline-block. Put that icon's span inside the h3 and it will always render as a single unit, just like the icon was a word in the h3. Since the icon is wrapped in a span, you can still target it individually if you need to.
Here's a fiddle illustrating how: 
[Making your icon an integral part of your heading](https://jsfiddle.net/45fgy0v7/)
(I started with your code and commented out what no longer applies so you can see the progression.)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are using Bootstrap and Font Awesome, so my fiddle reflects that.

https://jsfiddle.net/Vuice/Ljkoatog/

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
          <h3 style="display:inline;">We're Creative</h3>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```